# Why is this program(rather the segment) crashing the whole program

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I have been scratching my head to figure out why is my program is crashing. My aim was to scan a string and get frequency of each sub string !

The Real part where the program is crashing (M is a map of string,int type)
My Input: the string is "abab" and the program crashes when i=0 and j is equal to 3 just at the M[e]++ statement!

```
    for(i=0;str[i];i++)
        {

            char temp[5001];
            k=0;
            cout<<str[i]<<endl;
            for(j=i;str[j];j++)
                {
                    temp[k]=(char)str[j];
                    k++;
                    temp[k]='\0';
                    string e(temp);
                    M[e]++;
                    cout<<j<<endl;
                }
        }
```

**MAIN Method**

```
    int main()
    {
    ini();
    int t,N,i,j,Q,buff,k=0;
    char str[5001];
    scanf("%d",&t);
    map <string ,int > M;
    map <string , int >::iterator ii;
    for(;t--;)
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&N,&Q);
        scanf(" %s",str);
        for(i=0;str[i];i++)
            {

                char temp[5001];
                k=0;
                cout<<str[i]<<endl;
                for(j=i;str[j];j++)
                    {
                        temp[k]=(char)str[j];
                        k++;
                        temp[k]='\0';
                        string e(temp);
                        M[e]++;
                        cout<<j<<endl;
                    }
            }
        for(ii=M.begin();ii!=M.end();++ii)
                F[ii->second]++;
        F2[N]=F[N]%MOD;
        for(i=N;i>=1;i--)
            if(F[i])
                for(j=i-1;j>=1;j--)
                    F2[j]=(F[j]+((long long)F[i]%MOD*C(F[i],j)%MOD)%MOD)%MOD;
        for(i=0;i<Q;i++)
           {
                scanf("%d",&buff);
                printf("%d\n",F2[buff]);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Note

```
int F[5001],F2[5001];
```

are declared globally too.

Comment: may be better to use std::vector instead of int[]? And show what you want to get the output when the input string is equal to "abab". I think your problem has a simpler solution.

Comment: Now it crashes at the return 0 statement! Can you explain why?
 I dont have a vast knowledge about STL s . And Why is that I should use vector instead of int[]?? It is making the program run fine

Comment: Among othe problems, your program has a number of bounds-checking issues, so you are almost certainly invoking undefined behavior via an out-of-bounds array access -- in practice this means your are smashing your stack. One this happens, the place where your program crashes as reported by e.g. a debugger has absolutely nothing to do with where the original problem (invoking undefined behavior) occured.

Comment: I do not exactly get it where am I going out of bounds. str[i] or str[j] becomes 0 as soon as '\0' is encountered (ASCII value 0) .temp can never exceed str so it will always be in bounds. The program was crashing just in this loop before F2 and F1 were even exceeded...! 

Can you please explain in terms of my variables?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma i tested your code, with minor modifications, and it gives no errors, the issue could be with different user's inputs and having to validate them to make sure they are within your code's boundaries. If you want, i can post the code, but they were only minor changes which i can't guarantee is the problem.

Comment: That might be helpful please post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

#define MOD 10

using namespace std;

int C( int a, int b ){
    return 5;
}

int F[5001],F2[5001];

int main()
    {
    int t,N,i,j,Q,buff,k=0;
    string str(5001, ' ');
    cin >> t;//scanf("%d",&t);
    cin.ignore( 256, '\n' );
    map <string ,int > M;
    map <string , int >::iterator ii;
    for(;t--;)
    {
        cin >> N;
        cin.ignore( 256, '\n' );
        cin >> Q;
        cin.ignore( 256, '\n' );
        //scanf(" %s",str);
        getline(cin,str);
        for(i=0;str[i];i++)
            {

                char temp[5001];
                k=0;
                cout<<str[i]<<endl;
                for(j=i;str[j];j++)
                    {
                        temp[k]=(char)str[j];
                        k++;
                        temp[k]='\0';
                        string e(temp);
                        M[e]++;
                        cout<<j<<endl;
                    }
            }
        for(ii=M.begin();ii!=M.end();++ii)
                F[ii->second]++;
        F2[N]=F[N]%MOD;
        for(i=N;i>=1;i--)
            if(F[i])
                for(j=i-1;j>=1;j--)
                    cout << "hello";F2[j]=(F[j]+((long long)F[i]%MOD*C(F[i],j)%MOD)%MOD)%MOD;
        for(i=0;i<Q;i++)
           {
                scanf("%d",&buff);
                printf("%d\n",F2[buff]);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

For testing purposes, because there was no `MOD` and `C` definitions given, for `MOD` I used a constant `int`  and `C` an empty function that received those parameters and simply returned a value.

Instead of `scanf`, I used `cin` for the inputs and later `cin.ignore()` to clear the input buffer so that it won't skip the next `cin`. Changed `str` to type `string`. Used `getline` to get input for string, as this reads the enitre line from the input `cin`. And that is it for modifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for(i=0;str[i];i++)
        {
            for(j=0;str[j+i];j++)
            {
                M[str.substr(j,i+1)]++;
            }
        }
```

Replace internal two for loops with this and check whether it's crashing or not . If still that means you may be running this program on windows.In  that case use this.

```
        for(i=0;str[i];i++)
        {
            for(j=0;str[j+i];j++)
            {
                std::string sstr = str.substr(j,i+1);
                if ( M.find ( sstr ) == M.end() ){
                      M.insert( std::make_pair ( sstr , 0 ) ) ;
                }
                else
                M[str.substr(j,i+1)]++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: How does it matter.. If I use M[str++] .. Map sets the container to zero which is incremented